Name the educational hidden camera tv show about how people think
I'm trying to find a tv show that aired several years ago. It was an educational hidden camera show that featured how people's brains reacted in various situations. For example, in one episode people were asked to put together a wooden stool. In the test there were people in the background talking to each other and the person working on the chair was able to not be distracted and put the stool together no problem. But when someone was on their cell phone and they could only hear one half of the conversation, the person couldn't help but listen and get distracted trying to figure out what the other person was talking about. Another episode had people sitting in a car repair waiting room and seeing how they reacted to various situations such as if all of the other waiting customers started staring at them. Help name the show please!

Was it narrated by Neil Patrick Harris?

What channel was it aired on?

You're looking for Head Games on Discovery, a hidden camera show dealing with social experiments. Episode 1 had a scene where people kept staring at a person in a car wash waiting room. Episode 3 had a scene where a person was building a stool and was distracted more by a woman talking on her cellphone than by her talking without it. You can see the first scene here and the second here (though they're both dubbed).
Incidentally, a NatGeo show called Brain Games had a very similar premise to the staring prank, this time in a barbershop:




Thank you, Walt!!! I just recently watched a few episodes of Brain Games and it reminded me of the other show I had seen a few years ago but I just couldn't remember what it was called. You're awesome!
